# Vimeo Laravel API Issue - Invalid bucket error

Tags: php, laravel, api, vimeo-api

When I try to upload videos to Vimeo using Vimeo Laravel API, I am getting below error:

Client error: `POST https://files.tus.vimeo.com/files/vimeo-prod-src-tus-asia` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"error":"Invalid bucket"}

Here is the code:

```
public function postvideo(Request $request){
    $file = $request->file('video');
    $realpath = $file->getRealPath();
    Vimeo::upload($realpath);
}
```

Can you please someone help me to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved on December 2018, https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php/issues/189.
Upgrade vimeo/vimeo-api package to version 3.0.2